# My while loop does not end. Why does this happen?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I had made a while loop that is supposed to take a number between 11 and 100. it prints the first number and subtract by 1 every loop. the while loop is supposed to break every time it hits a double number like 99 or 44. This is my basic code but I'm not sure why the loop doesn't break.

```
x = input()
x = int(x)

print (x)
while x != int(11) or int(22) or int(33) or int(44) or int(55) or int(66) or int(77) or int(88) or int(99):
    x -= 1
    print (x)
```

Comment: Side note: you can replace `int(11)` with `11`.

Comment: thanks it helped to make a list and use 'not in'